# The application installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest, failed-installation

[image]

While running project in mobile device I got error:

> Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Please can anyone help me to sort out this error?

```
 <application xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.multidex.instrumentation">

 <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Splash">
            <intent-filter android:exported="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:exported="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.app" />
            </intent-filter>

 </activity>

 </application>
```

I have tried some solutions to add  `android:exported="true"` for activity, intent-filter and package name should be in lowercase but didn't work for me.

Comment: Don't look at the AndroidManifet.xml in your project but in the generated APK files. Every used library can add entries (which can cause this error). So use Android Studio APK Analyzer to see the final AndridManifest.xml and then check which library has added the malformed entry.

Comment: Is this the full manifest? The provided part is missing *manifest* and *application* parts.

Comment: @Robert I have generated APK to check every used library(this project used lots of libraries). In the final AndridManifest.xml  modules <Activity> tag missing android:exported="true", does every tag need exported property? I thought only entry point LAUNCHER activity need this.

Comment: @Ariczek  AndridManifest.xml files size is too big and can't post here. I have updated <Application> in question. Is there anything wrong with the Application tag?

Comment: Every activity has to have the exported flag. May be one of the used libraries you use is outdated or not designed for recent Android versions?

Comment: Try to comment on some dependencies and reinstall the app. You can check malformed entry in Merged Manifest using this path: `project\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug`

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your suggestions. There are a number of libraries that a lower version I have updated to the latest. but some libraries latest version do not support targetSDK 33. In merger manifest it's showing the targetSDK-31 event I set it to 33 in the app-level gradle file. How can I solve this?

Comment: The exported entries are already required for targetSDK 31 so this shouldn't be a problem. If there is still an outdated library adding problematic entries you have the common choices: stop using the library or contact the library author or try fixing the library yourself by manipulating the aar file (I wouldn't recommend the latter).